# Mantener tamaño del elemento al ser afectado por un media query

Tags: css, responsive, navbar, mediaqueries

Estoy aprendiendo a manejarme con las media query y me ha surgido un problema que no veo muy bien como solucionar. He ajustado mi media query para que cuando la pantalla tenga un tamaño determinado, las opciones de mi navbar desaparezcan y solo quede el espacio negro. (con el fin de después habilitar un menú hamburgesa)

El problema es que al quitar los elementos del navbar, su tamaño disminuye verticalmente, debido a la ausencia de elementos. ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el navbar siga ocupando el mismo espacio con sus elementos y sin ellos?

```css
#navbar {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  background: black;
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}
#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 570px) {
  #navbar a {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Productos</a>
  <a href="#">Log In</a>
  <a href="#">About Us</a>
  <a href="#">Contactanos</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si solo necesitas que no sean visibles, podes utilizar `visibility: hidden;`

#### Ejemplo:

```css
#navbar {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  background: black;
  font-family: 'Nanum Gothic', sans-serif;
}
#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  #navbar a {
    visibility: hidden;
    /* Y para que no ocupen lugar a lo ancho */
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Productos</a>
  <a href="#">Log In</a>
  <a href="#">About Us</a>
  <a href="#">Contactanos</a>
</nav>
```

---

Referencia:

- [CSS - visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/visibility)